# Linux SO_RCVLOWAT being violated by epoll according to FIONREAD

Tags: linux, tcp, socket

The more traditional way of dealing with sockets is to have a buffer per connection, and to incrementally read as many bytes as possible once the socket becomes readable.

With a framed protocol operating over TCP, a more efficient way would be to leverage the fact that the kernel already buffers data per connection. Linux provides the SO_RCVLOWAT flag to prevent poll/select/epoll from marking the socket as readable until the desired number of bytes are available. This can be combined with the FIONREAD ioctl to read how many bytes are immediately available for consumption to prevent partial reads in the processing loop. Under this structure, a full frame could be read at once into a single shared buffer (sized at maximum frame size) and processed in-place, ready to be overwritten by the next frame.

However, my implementation breaks. Epoll starts to fire READ events even when FIONREAD reports a value less than SO_RCVLOWAT. A call to recv() with MSG_PEEK returns a value matching FIONREAD, so they are in agreement that the socket does *not* have at least SO_RCVLOWAT bytes immediately available for reading, and thus should not be consider readable by epoll.

Here is my implementation, and some sample server/client code to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/MrSonicMaster/broken

Notably:

```c
static void handle_reads(proto_state *s) {
  uint32_t bav;
  ioctl(s->fd, FIONREAD, &bav);

  uint32_t lowat;
  getsockopt(s->fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVLOWAT, &lowat,
             &(socklen_t){sizeof lowat});

  printf("EPOLL FIRED READ EVENT FIONREAD=%d SO_RCVLOWAT=%d\n", bav, lowat);

  if (bav < lowat) {
    /* debug code */
#define CAP (1 << 15)
    uint8_t *largebuf = alloca(CAP);
    ssize_t recvd = recv(s->fd, largebuf, CAP, MSG_PEEK);
    printf(
        "is FIONREAD lying? actual bav via recv with MSG_PEEK = %ld (cap %d)\n",
        recvd, CAP);
  }

  printf("BAV %d NEED %d\n", bav, s->hdr.len);

  msghdr hdr = s->hdr;

  while (bav >= hdr.len) {
    ssize_t read_bytes = read(s->fd, rbuffer, hdr.len);

    if (read_bytes != hdr.len) {
      fprintf(stderr, "WTF HOW? BROKE!\n");
      break;
    }

    bav -= read_bytes;

    if (s->need_hdr) {
      hdr = *(msghdr *)rbuffer;

      if (hdr.len > 16384) {
        fprintf(stderr, "msg too large %d\n", hdr.len);
        close(s->fd);
        handle_close(s);
        return;
      }

      // printf("READ HEADER, CODE %d LEN %d (udat %d)\n", hdr.code, hdr.len,
      //       hdr.udat);

      if (hdr.len == 0) {
        /* handle zero-length message */
        s->frame_cb(s, hdr, NULL);
        hdr.len = sizeof(msghdr);
        continue;
      }

      s->need_hdr = 0;
    } else {
      // printf("READ FRAME, CODE %d LEN %d\n", hdr.code, hdr.len);
      s->frame_cb(s, hdr, rbuffer);
      hdr.len = sizeof(msghdr);
      s->need_hdr = 1;
    }
  }

  s->hdr = hdr;

out_setlowat:
  if (hdr.len != s->lowat) {
    setsockopt(s->fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVLOWAT, &hdr.len, sizeof hdr.len);
    s->lowat = hdr.len;

    printf("SET lowat %d\n", s->lowat);
  }
}

...

void proto_loop() {
  int nevents = epoll_wait(ep, events, MAX_EVENTS, 0);
  if (nevents == -1) {
    perror("proto_loop() epoll_wait()");
    return;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < nevents; i++) {
    struct epoll_event event = events[i];

    void *ptr = (void *)(((uintptr_t)event.data.ptr) & ~1);

    // printf("EVENT %d %p\n", event.events, ptr);

    if (ptr != event.data.ptr) {
      listen_desc *d = ptr;
      handle_accept(d->fd, d->cb);
      return;
    }

    if (event.events & EPOLLERR || event.events & EPOLLHUP ||
        event.events & EPOLLRDHUP)
      handle_close(ptr);
    else {
      if (event.events & EPOLLIN)
        handle_reads(ptr);
      if (event.events & EPOLLOUT)
        handle_writes(ptr);
    }
  }
}
```

Under all configuration I have tried, eventually it will get stuck:

```
EPOLL FIRED READ EVENT FIONREAD=29103 SO_RCVLOWAT=14764
BAV 29103 NEED 14764
got frame with code 0 len 14764
got frame with code 0 len 5232
SET lowat 9647
EPOLL FIRED READ EVENT FIONREAD=9083 SO_RCVLOWAT=9647
is FIONREAD lying? actual bav via recv with MSG_PEEK = 9083 (cap 32768)
EPOLL FIRED READ EVENT FIONREAD=9083 SO_RCVLOWAT=9647
is FIONREAD lying? actual bav via recv with MSG_PEEK = 9083 (cap 32768)
EPOLL FIRED READ EVENT FIONREAD=9083 SO_RCVLOWAT=9647
is FIONREAD lying? actual bav via recv with MSG_PEEK = 9083 (cap 32768)
EPOLL FIRED READ EVENT FIONREAD=9083 SO_RCVLOWAT=9647
is FIONREAD lying? actual bav via recv with MSG_PEEK = 9083 (cap 32768)
...
```

I use level triggered epoll, and disabled kernel buffer auto tuning by forcing the buffers to a static size. It does not seem to matter how large or small I set them (so long as it is sufficiently large to hold a full frame without the congestion window fully closing, ex. > 2x max frame size)

Another notable thing, closing server will not generate an EPOLLRDHUP event on the client.

Unfortunately, I don't seem to find examples of other people doing it like this, so I don't know if its even expected to work.

Answer (score 1):

So, I actually solved this a while ago but did not get around to posting the answer.

When a nonblocking Linux socket runs out of buffer space, it will violate the SO_RCVLOWAT setting and will be marked as readable anyways. This behavior is not documented anywhere. The only mention was a couple of commits to the Linux kernel source tree. I did not originally believe this to be the case as the code exhibiting the issue should not have encountered this issue - I believe that was caused by additional undocumented optimization done on UNIX domain sockets, causing the senders SNDBUF to be piped to the receivers RCVBUF in a way that batched sends into a larger chunk than could fit at once (larger than the individual sends should have been). I can confirm this is the problem as calling getsockopt() with SO_ERROR returns ENOBUFS when SO_RCVLOWAT was violated.

The solution to make this work over UNIX domain sockets is to ensure that the receivers RCVBUF is large enough to hold more than the entire senders SNDBUF, such that whatever optimization/batching Linux is doing internally does not break the program logic.